# A contest? A contest! But what prizes?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Android.SE will soon be hosting a contest to reward new and established community members who gain certain achievements within a set time frame.

To an extent, the rules will resemble those established for last year's [Super User 1 Year Anniversary Super Contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/):

> Four weeks, four winners each week, and the fabulous prizes are appropriately super-user-y.
>
> 1. The best rookie performance of a new user in that week, as measured by the Super User leagues, will receive a 32 GB USB key.
> 2. The highest reputation produced in that week, as measured by the Super User leagues, will receive a 22″ LCD monitor.
> 3. The “most awesome” new Super User question or answer that week, that most embodies the type of Q&A that make the site great — as judged by the Super User community moderators — will receive a two bay NAS device.
> 4. The most useful Meta Super User question or answer of the week — as judged by the Super User community moderators — gets a Super User t-shirt and stickers.

But we need a different set of Android-y prizes. And I'm not sure we need 4 separate prizes.

What do you guys want? What already released or soon-to-be-released devices make you drewl? Any Android accessories?

What's hot!?

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't mind a Bluetooth headset.

Gift certificate for the Android Market/Amazon App Store/*et cetera*?

I suggest against a case. There are too many form-factors out there.

I've already got one, but one of the plastic Android toys would be cool to give away.

There's some new cool ones out: http://www.neatoshop.com/product/Android-Mini-Collectible-Series-02-Blind-Box?tag=1588

Comment: Al, can you point me to a headset in the range of $50-$120 that you and other Android users want?

Answer (score 7):

I want a Nexus 3 when it's released (whenever Ice Cream Sandwich is released).  I can only assume everyone else shares my craving for this device — or, at least, would be extremely happy to win one.

Comment: I would like the US (Verizon) Samsung GS II if it would ever come out :)