# A Bluetooth headset giveaway?

Tags: discussion

Keep an eye out for [a Bionic contest](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/585/a-contest-a-contest-but-what-prizes) as soon as the phone is officially released. But to tide us over until then, Android.SE will be hosting a Bluetooth headset giveaway during the middle of next week or the following week.

But what headset should we give?

Check out these options:

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2369586,00.asp

Which do you want? Know of an awesome headset not included?

Lemme know what ya think!

Comment: I personally have a pair of Motorola ROKR S9-HD.  They're great for running/exercising, but I wouldn't want to wear them all day. They have a mic, but cover both ears so they wouldn't be good for driving hands free.

Comment: Ugh... earbuds.